# Как можно сохранить файл на телефоне из react-native приложения, (отредоктировал его в TextInput) положил в state

Tags: react-native

Пробывал таким путем

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'

const [file, setFile] = useState('')

    const saveFile = async (filename, mimetype) => {
        const permissions = await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync()
        if (permissions.granted) {
            const directoryUri = permissions.directoryUri
            await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(directoryUri, filename, mimetype)
                .then(async (fileUri) => {
                    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, file, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8 })
                }).catch(err => console.log(`Error>>> ${err}`))
        }
    }
```

Маленький файл сохраняет, а большой нет. A мне надо редактировать файлы чуть побольше.

Может есть другие библиотеки для редактирования и сохранения файлов на девайсе?